# Node Cannot Leave the Cluster in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I created a cluster of nodes for my data analysis project. I wanted to test my project by removing a node from the cluster to see if it handles it effectively. The code for removing the node is as follows:

```js
const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
const store = factory.getStore({
    "host": '239.0.0.1',
    "port": 31999,
    "clusterName": "defaultCluster",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
});

// For connecting to the GridDB Server we have to make containers and specify the schema.
const conInfo = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "gdpanalysis",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["Country", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["1999", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2000", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2001", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2002", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2003", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2004", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2005", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2006", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2007", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2008", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2009", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2010", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2011", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2012", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2013", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2014", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2015", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2016", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2017", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2018", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2019", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2020", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2021", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["2022", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});

Container container = gridStore.getContainer("myContainer");
Row row = container.createRow();
row.setString("name", "John Doe");
row.setInteger("age", 30);
container.put(row);

// Attempting to remove a node from the cluster
GridClusterInfo clusterInfo = gridStore.getClusterInfo();
clusterInfo.removeNode();
```

However, I was unable to do it and received the following error:

```bash
[Server] 180030

[Description] Node cannot leave the cluster
```

Is there any authentication or firewall that needs to be disabled from GridDB to allow for that? And is there any risk in doing that? I appreciate any help provided.

P.S. I ran GridDB on Administrator settings.

Answer (score 1):

GridDB CE no longer supports clustering (one node only). To do proper clustering, you must use the enterprise version of GridDB, so that is perhaps the issue you are facing